# Remove duplicates records on database SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

If I have a table `leads`

```
id|phone|name
__|_____|_____
1 |123  |Test
2 |123  |Test
3 |111  |Test2
4 |123  |Test
```

How Do I remove the duplicate phone numbers in there? So if there is 3 records with `123` as phone number, the other 2 duplicates should be delete.

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far?

Comment: I only know the basic delete like DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 3; . I don't know what is the condition for my scenario. I tried googling and all I see is in INNER JOINS so I am confuse

Comment: duplicated with many other questions about duplicate. please give yourself a try before ask a question like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY phone, name ORDER BY id)
    FROM tbl    
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE RowNum > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from you comments you are obviously new to database. so i can tell you to try group by. there are many way to solve the problem you asked

in your case the easiest way is group by

```
select min(id) as id ,phone,name from leads group by phone,name.
```

and you still can do it with row_number.

the link Music gave in the comment is good. you should try to understand it by yourself